# Python seach JSON dictionary for specific value and return that key

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to search each description entered in the JSON file to search for a match then return the hash key. Example: A search for 'Cat Photo' should return the hash key 'QmVQ8dU8cpNezxZHG2oc3xQi61P2n'. Any help would be great.

```
searchTerm = raw_input('Enter search term: ')
with open('hash.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    hashlist = data['hashlist']

if searchTerm in hashlist == True:
        print key
    else:
        print "not found"
```

Sample of JSON file:

```
   {
"hashlist": {
    "QmVZATT8cQM3kwBrGXBjuKfifvrE": {
        "description": "Test Video",
        "url": ""
    },
    "QmVQ8dU8cpNezxZHG2oc3xQi61P2n": {
        "description": "Cat Photo",
        "url": ""
    },
    "QmYdWbMy8wPA7V12bX7hf2zxv64AG": {
        "description": "Test Dir",
        "url": ""
    }
}
}%
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a JSON dictionary; there are JSON objects, and `json.load` uses them to create instances of the `dict` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to construct a dict to map from the `description` to hashcode:

```
d = {v['description']: h for h, v in hashlist.items()}
```

Then you can access it simply by:

```
d['Cat Photo']
```

Comment: This works great! I just added print d[searchTerm] and it works. How would I add a "not found" if it does not find it? @liliscent

Comment: @TroyWilson `d.get('xxx', 'Not found')`, `get()` will provide a default value if key not exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
results = [k for k in d['hashlist'] if 'Cat' in d['hashlist'][k]['description']]
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

Should sort you, let me know if you have problems.

Comment: I changed dictInstance to hashlist and I get this error ValueError: too many values to unpack.

Comment: Try it now, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
hash = next(k for k,v in hashlist.items() if v['description'] == 'Cat Photo')
```

Remember this will throw error if cat photo is not found in description key